# Алгоритм Беллман Форд

Tags: алгоритм

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как путь связан с номером шага в цикле при нахождении кратчайшего пути?

Comment: какая связь с `c#`?

Comment: извините, неверно указал метку.

Answer (score 1):

Метод Беллмана-Форда основан на идее динамического программирования. На шаге `k` внешнего цикла он находит кратчайший путь, содержащий не более `k` ребёр. Таким образом, на шаге `n-1` (последний шаг), мы имеем кратчайшие пути в полном смысле этого слова (если путь не проходит через отрицательный цикл).

Comment: Спасибо.Еще вопрос. Есть граф с отрицательным циклом. Как из всего графа выделить те вершины, которые образуют этот цикл с помощью массива родителей?

Comment: Ну, например, так. Если `j` - вершина, а `i=p[j]` - предшествующая ей, то если `d[j]>d[i]+s[i,j]`, где `d[]` - массив величин кратчайшего пути (результат работы алгоритма), а `s[i,j]` - длина ребра `(i,j)`, то вершины i и j входят в цикл отрицательного веса. Нужно выполнить релаксацию данного ребра и смотреть, есть ли ещё такие пары вершин. Возможно, это не единственный способ, вообще полезно почитать [вот это](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ford_bellman), там есть ответы на все Ваши вопросы.